# At a particular K-point (Monkhorst Pack) grid, SCF calculation is not converging

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, computational-chemistry, k-points, materials-engineering

During a convergence test of (MoS2 2x2x1) monolayer using Quantum ESPRESSO, I tried several K-point Monkhorst-Pack grids. According to my understanding, the calculation time and computational cost should decrease with decreasing K-points density.

However as I tried 2x2x1 K-point grid, the calculation was found to be not converging (it stopped after electron_maxstep 80). Upon changing K-points to 3x3x1, I found that the calculation is able to converge within few iterations (~17 iterations). Similarly, It  converged for (4x4x1), (5x5x1), and (6x6x1) grids.

**My question: what is the physical reason behind this non-convergence at this particular K-point?**

For your reference, the following are my basic input and output files:

Input file [input.in](https://github.com/joyalsunny18/convergence-testing/blob/main/pwscf-k-point-221.in)

output file for 2x2x1 sampling [output.out](https://github.com/joyalsunny18/convergence-testing/blob/main/pwscf-k-point-221.out)

output file for 3x3x1 sampling [output.out](https://github.com/joyalsunny18/convergence-testing/blob/main/pwscf-k-point-331.outhttps://)

output file for 4x4x1 sampling  [output.out](https://github.com/joyalsunny18/convergence-testing/blob/main/pwscf-k-point-441.out)

output file for 5x5x1 sampling  [output.out](https://github.com/joyalsunny18/convergence-testing/blob/main/pwscf-k-point-551.out)

K-point convergence data summarized [conv.ods](https://github.com/joyalsunny18/convergence-testing/blob/main/k_point_conv.ods)

Comment: Please see this: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5, please also fix the grammar.

Comment: Are you aware that the letter "i" needs to be capitalized when used on its own for the word that you used in your question?

Comment: I do not know the true cause as of yet, but when you have such reality-destroying situations, you should simplify the problem as much as you can. For example, you should consider only the primitive unit cell, and let QE fill in the cell parameters as much as you can. i.e. insert only the lattice parameter, not define the cell. You should also set one of the Mo to be the origin and the S to be positive and negative z, i.e. maximise symmetry. Your atomic positions should be machine precision 1/3 and 1/6 and so forth.

Comment: And your system is showing that there is no magnetisation. You should switch that off to save on computation time and resources.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent
If the situation is related to complexity in  input ,How come I got convergence and expected results for (111),(331),(441),(551) and (661) grids ? Here my doubt is that, is this somehow related to physical concept of sampling the Brillouin zone ?

Comment: Every k point that is in (221) is in (441) and in (661), so that it is more likely to just be a fluke in the computation. I'm trying to get you to get (221) to work.